# how much time did apple provide to run application in background in iphone os

Tags: iphone, process, background

Hi i have 1 problem to run application in background.

I have task to run the application in the background and at some specific time give alert and check it.

So my question is that Can apple allowed me to run application in background for long time. and if they provide then is their some specific time for it.

Please provide me help for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apple documentation goes over all of this pretty well. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) is the link.